# Spring REST APi returns empty result on search using PagingAndSortingRepository

Tags: java, spring, rest, api, jpa

I am trying to build a REST API that returns a list of all transactions made by a user with a specific senderId, yet I have some issues retrieving the list itself.
A version of this works fine for my Customer functionality with age as a stand-in for senderId, so I don't understand why this is causing issues.
Whenever I search using PagingAndSortingRepository my page returns an empty JSON, like so:

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "transactions" : [ ]
  },
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/transactions/search/findTransactionsBySenderId?senderid=1"
    }
  }
}
```

I have a Transaction class:

```
@Entity
public class Transaction {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Long transactionId;
    private Long senderId;
    private Account.AccountType senderAccountType;
    private Long recipientId;
    private double amountTransferred = 0;
    private Date transactionDate;

    public Transaction() {
    }

    // Getters & Setters
```

I have a TransactionRepository:

```
public interface TransactionRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Transaction, Long> {
    Iterable<Transaction> findTransactionsBySenderId(@Param("senderId") Long senderId);
}
```

And a TransactionController:

```
@RestController
public class TransactionController {

    // TransactionController
    @Autowired
    TransactionRepository transactionRepository;

    @GetMapping(path = "/transactions")
    public Iterable<Transaction> getTransactions() {
        return transactionRepository.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping(path = "/transactions", consumes = {"application/json"})
    public Transaction createTransaction(@RequestBody Transaction transaction) {

        transactionRepository.save(transaction);
        return transaction;
    }
}
```

And my DB looks like this:
[image: mysql database]

Comment: Which controller API you are calling? Looks like missing findTransactionsBySenderId in your controller.

Comment: I thought so too, but in my CustomerRepository I have these:

    Customer findCustomerByUsernameAndPassword(@Param("username") String username, @Param("password") String password);

    Customer findCustomerByEmail(@Param("email") String email);

    Customer findCustomerByUsername(@Param("username") String username);

without anything corresponding in the Controller and they work as intended

Comment: This is strange, without an endpoint how do we call the API? 